# Change bottom automatically according to div's with parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, jquery-isotope

I'm creating Isotope layout, to make it responsive I've created column width percent unit with hover caption effect. Everything works fine except responsive mode. I want to change bottom of caption automatically according div's width parent but I don't know how to archive this. Can you help me out?

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dqfm3gj7/2/

**HTML**

```
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                            <h2>blog title</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item item-width2">  <a href="#">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/RVHcLal.jpg" alt="Image" />

                                    <figcaption>
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                            <h2>blog title</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada, nulla lacus rhoncus nisi, nec fringilla massa urna quis eros. Integer faucibus placerat dui sit amet volutpat. Curabitur suscipit rhoncus lectus, sit amet fermentum lacus interdum sed.</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item">  <a href="#">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JkTsi3A.jpg" alt="Image" />

                                    <figcaption>
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                            <h2>blog title</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item">  <a href="#">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JkTsi3A.jpg" alt="Image" />

                                    <figcaption>
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                            <h2>blog title</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item">  <a href="#">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JkTsi3A.jpg" alt="Image" />

                                    <figcaption>
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                            <h2>blog title</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item">  <a href="#">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JkTsi3A.jpg" alt="Image" />

                                    <figcaption>
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                            <h2>blog title</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="item">  <a href="#">
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/JkTsi3A.jpg" alt="Image" />

                                    <figcaption>
                                        <div class="title">
                                            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                                            <h2>blog title</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper tincidunt semper. Pellentesque condimentum, ligula non rutrum malesuada.</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end blog-container -->
</div>
<!-- end blog-section -->
```

**CSS**

```
#blog-container{
    max-width: 1140px;
}

    #blog-container:after{
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }

figure{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}

figcaption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -71%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: bottom .5s;
    color: #615b51;
}

    figcaption h2,
    figcaption .title p{
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.item-width2 figcaption{
    bottom: -86%;
}

    figcaption:hover{
        bottom: 0;
    }

.item,
.item-sizer{
    width: 19.298%;
    height: auto;
}

.item-width2{
    width: 39.5%;
}

.item{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

@media(max-width: 736px){
    .item,
    .item-sizer,
    .item-width2{
        width: 48.641%;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var $container = jQuery('#blog-container');

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    percentPosition: true,
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    masonry:{
        columnWidth: '.item-sizer',
        gutter: 10
    }
});
```

Comment: can you specify more like if parent div width gets 460px i want bottom of figcaption class to be 10px. can you precisely say that? It can be achieved by Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: Hi @divy3993 Please show me the jQuery code.

Comment: JQuery code for? I asked to mention like above comment so that it would be easy for anyone to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, your problem is that when the page gets narrower and the `@media` rule is applied, all the tiles get the same dimension but the labels (`figcaption`) do not.

Have you tried applying the same `bottom` value to all `figcaption` tags inside that `@media` rule?

```
@media(max-width: 736px){

    ...

    figcaption {
        bottom: -71%; // Set the value you want all them to have
    }
}
```

If you end up having more complex styles and you have problems trying to have that rule applied to all the different `figcaption` tags in your page you would have to check the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of those rules and set a more specific one inside the `@media` block. You can check that using this tool: http://specificity.keegan.st/

You could also use the [`!important` annotation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) on the `bottom` (or any other) property.

**EDIT:**

If you want to make the `bottom` property value depend on the dimension of the tiles you should set its value in `%` or you could also use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to do *some* operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) with `%` and any other different units (e.g. `bottom: calc(71% - 1em)`).

You could also use multiple CSS media queries for different page widths: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried but it doesn't work. Because the div's width change automatically so I can't set specific bottom for each size.

Comment: I would try to do that using multiple media queries depending on the page's width. That would **not** result in a "_specific_ bottom for _each_ size", but would allow you to have better control of its value if using `%` is not enough. You could add queries for page's width less than `300px`, from `300px` to `399px`, from `400px` to `499px` and so on.